# Resize partition without using LVM

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, disk-usage, resize2fs

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed on remote server and I have requested another `20GB` for my `/dev/vda2` partition (now its 20GB), so the total size would be `40GB`. Since `vda2` is full of very valuable data (disk usage is 100%), I want to extend it.

Now, I have searched for ways to do it but I found out my `LVM` is not configured, or at least it looks like it, because when I run for example `vgdisplay` nothing happens. Then I tried `vgscan` and it says `Reading volume groups from cache.` but that's it.

I have tried to follow this tutorial https://www.linuxtechi.com/extend-lvm-partitions/ but since I can't run

`# vgdisplay < Volume-Group-Name>`

because I don't know my `volume-group-name`, I am stuck.

What can I do ? I am looking for the safest way and also easiest since I have 2 databases running there, I backed up all my data from them but I really don't want to set it all up once again...

Just for info, when I run `fdisk -l` I get this:

[image]

**Edit:**

this is what I got regarding to answer below:

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
label: gpt
label-id: 88501878-0C4F-486D-B09A-1AD0A6C81982
device: /dev/vda
unit: sectors
first-lba: 34
last-lba: 41943006

/dev/vda1 : start=        2048, size=        2048, type=21686148-6449-6E6F-744E-656564454649, uuid=6FA9DDEF-760F-4276-9DF0-B8A62F9C51BD
/dev/vda2 : start=        4096, type=0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4, uuid=E0912389-7C07-41F7-A21E-B8B131F2C491
```

Comment: Well yes, thats what I have found out too. I had no idea when installing system, that I need LVM ...didn't even know what its for. But now I have no idea what to do and I need it bad.

Comment: Remember to check whether your VPS provider supports starting virtual machines from LVM.

Comment: there is no way I can reinstall system, copy data, etc...I am looking for a solution as it is now, there must be some way

Comment: If your VPS provider alllows to grow virtual disks, it can be done. but we cannot guess it.

Comment: Are... you sure this is LVM?  This doesn't look like an LVM setup...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `sfdisk` to resize the 2nd partition.

```
# write the current partition table into a machine readable text file 
sfdisk --dump /dev/vda > /var/tmp/vda.old
cp /var/tmp/vda.old /var/tmp/vda.new
# also copy vda.old to another machine to have a safe backup

# edit the dump to set the new size for partion 2
# (you may remove the size parameter ", size= 1234" and the
# whole line "last-lba: 1234" to get the max possible size)
vim /var/tmp/vda.new

# now apply the edited partition table to the harddisk
sfdisk --no-reread /dev/vda </var/tmp/vda.new

# check if it looks good, otherwise repair/try again
fdisk -l /dev/vda


# after reboot, resize the filesystem too, for example in case of ext{2,3,4}
resize2fs /dev/vda2
```

Note, you can do this without using LVM because there is free space on your HD directly after the partition you want to resize. With LVM you would not have to reboot and also the whole resizing steps would look a bit less dangerous. So in general I would recommend to use LVM from the beginning, when installing the server. But for you it should work here also without LVM.

Comment: I don't understand the last part, is this what I can apply to my filesystem?

Comment: when I got to step to apply edited partition, I got a message in RED saying that disk is currently in use, that I should unmount all file systems and swapoff all swap partitions on this disk, or use `--no-reread flag` to suppress this check. what now?

Comment: okay, I used `--force` flag as it said, I updated my question with a picture of what it says

Comment: okay so I run: `/sfdisk /dev/vda < /var/tmp/vda.old --force` , I got back output as updated in my question, please check if its all good, cause if I loose it, ...

Comment: Updated the comment how to edit the size parameter to get the max possible size. (remove the whole size parameter inclusive one comma, not only the former value).

Comment: alright, now I got new response, see updated question, please check if its all good..so I can reboot

Comment: Hm,  the "new" size of partition 2 is still 20G. Are you sure you applied the edited `vda.new` where the whole size parameter is removed?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. It is 20G but the end is set to `41943006` and it was `20...` before...

Comment: 41943006 sectors are ~20G. Could you post the content of your file `vda.new`. Please post it as simple copy/pasted text instead of screenshot.

Comment: okay, check updated now

Comment: Ah, there is still the `last-lba ` line with the old disk size. You have to remove that line too, to get the max size.

Comment: Yea, that's what I thoug after you said 419..sectors is 20G...okay now it shows 40G....reboot save now?

Comment: Yes, reboot should work hopefully.